# NPM: Multiple same named prehooks

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-scripts

Can I have multiple same named prehooks in my package.json?

For e.g (Using two `pretest`):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
     ...
    "pretest": "eslint ignore file ...",
    "pretest": "eslint --ignore-pattern '.someFolder/*'"
  }
```

Is there a better/sophisticated approach, other than using `&&` or what I am using already?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot have multiple keys of the same name in a JavaScript object so by that definition, you cannot use the above format

Answer (score 0):

Here's a module I came across earlier that might be helpful in making it easier to work with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
     ...
    "pretest":"run-s pretest:*",
    "pretest:1": "eslint ignore file ...",
    "pretest:2": "eslint --ignore-pattern '.someFolder/*'"
  }
```